# Fluent nHibernate some kind of flat table

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

i have one problem (obviously :) )
Is it possible to make dynamic queries in nHibernate in that way...
I have many tables (let we say: User, City, Country, Continet,...) is it possible to flaten this data so i do not need to know joins between this tables (get continent for user, without making join user.city, city.country, coutry.continent)?

The point is i want to some kind flatten data, so user can dynamically select data on user interface without knowing data model behind application?

It will be great that someone gave me at least idea how to make this, or if it's possible...

One example on web is GoogleAnalytics Custom reports (you can drag dimensions and metrics on UI and get results)

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using Fluent NHibernate, which means that, assuming your domain model is structured correctly, you should not need to use any joins.

"Flattening" the data is a UI concern, not a database concern, so you shouldn't flatten your data model or simplify it for the UI unless you absolutely have to.

Let's assume you have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to filter users by a certain country, the LINQ query for this (assuming NHibernate 3) would be:

```
var country = session.Single<Country>(x => x.Name == "Africa");
session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.City.Country == country);
```

Comment: Yes, that is simple, but with many more tables i can not predict what entity will user select...
It could be city, coutry, continent, user...
With this i mean group by (city, country, continent, user,...)
Ok, i need to add one more table "Visits" 
I want to know "Dynamically" how many visits was from country, or city, or continet, or user, or could be product,...

Comment: Hmm, the only way I know of how to do this is to give the user the ability to do these things on the client side, and then program the server to filter things appropriately based on the user's criteria. I'm not sure if there's a more generic way of handling it and in fact, may not be a good idea because you could run into `SELECT N+1` issues.

Comment: I'm also thinking about some kind of table that represents relations between tables in my database. From this i can get relations and if user wants Continent and Visits ( "Continent.Name" and "Visits.NoOfVisits") i can dynamically search connection from Visits to Continent (Visits - City - Country - Continent) and then retrieve data with nHibernate.
Just think out loud, but i think that could be solution (mucking this all day long, uf)